# Create a form in php to and get the values of fields and create a url

Tags: php, html

I have to create a .php file in which there are three fields.
First is url in which user have to enter the url.
Second is name in which user will enter name.
Third is password where user will enter password.
There is submit button at the bottom of the page.

What i have to do is to create another url and have to send url entered by user then some string that i want to include in the url and then the username.

like

```
url_entered_user/some_constant=username_entered_by_user

http://url_entered_user/auth/totara2database/manualcron.php?user_name=username_entered_by_user
```

this will be the final url.

Please help

Comment: give some codes to start with....

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: <html>
<body>

<form action='urlcreated' method='post'>
url of totara: <input type='text' name='url'><br>  
Name: <input type='text' name='name'><br>  
password: <input type='text' name='password'><br>  
<input type='submit'>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the data from the form in php file urlcreated.php which you should have in action field of your form. And inside the php file:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$returned_url = "http://".$url."/auth/totara2database/manualcron.php?user_name=".$name.";
```

This way you can have in your php file the desired url in the $returned_url variable. Although i guess something is missing since you are not using anywhere the password you ask form the user.

**EDIT:** *(after comment)*
The general idea you can take it from a tutorial about how you handle html forms with php from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) or [another tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php/)

Without knowing the basics will be really difficult to go on even with the help i or anyone else might provide.

Comment: <html>
<body>

<form action=$returned_url method='post'>
url of totara: <input type='text' name='url'><br>  
Name: <input type='text' name='name'><br>  
password: <input type='text' name='password'><br>  
<input type='submit'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) 
{
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $url    = $_POST["url"];

        
       
}
$returned_url = "http://".$url."/auth/totara2database/manualcron.php?user_name=".$name."";
?>
You mean to say i have to do this thing

Comment: no you don't change your initial form which user give you his info you just edit this: action='urlcreated'  to this ---> action='urlcreated.php'. And then you create a file named urlcreated.php in the same directory the form file is and put inside the code i gave you in my answer. Finally you have in your php file in the variable  $returned_url the outcome you want.

Comment: What i have to do is to pass the linkwhich i will obtain in  $returned_url as a form action.

Comment: You have to give the whole picture, where you want to pass it and why you can't pass it from the php file?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<form action='$returned_url' method='post'>
url of totara: <input type='text' name='url'><br>       
Name: <input type='text' name='name'><br>       
password: <input type='text' name='password'><br>       
<input type='submit'>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<!-- http://localhost/totara/auth/totara2database/manualcron.php?user_name=name -->
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) 
{
        $username = $_POST["name"];
        $url    = $_POST["url"];



}
echo $username;
echo $url;
?>

$returned_url = "http://".$url."/auth/totara2database/manualcron.php?user_name=".$name.";
```

I actually want this thing.

Comment: in order to get that url though you need to either echo it or pass it some where else or do more with it through PHP. As it is now, the script just stores the URL. If you echo it or put it in a disabled text field then it can be copied by the user